# Position aside part way up in paragraph with CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm writing a blog post using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) in markdown with the [kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/) library. I have a true aside that contains ["content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content."](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element)  The aside logically goes with the first paragraph of my blog post.  I would like to float the aside next to the first paragraph, ideally part way down it.

The problem is, how can I move the aside up so it is at least part way into the first paragraph?

My HTML (I've translated the markdown to HTML for simplicity):

```html
<article>
  <h1>Blog Title</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph...</p>
  <aside>
    <h3>Aside Heading</h3>
    <p>Aside content...</p>
  </aside>
  <p>My second paragraph...</p>
</article>
```

My CSS:

```
aside
{
  float: right;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

I want something like this:

```
Blog Title

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac consequat erat, eu
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus      +---------------+
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pellentesque   | Aside here    |
pretium felis, et adipiscing ante dapibus eget. Aenean    |               |
nec lacinia eros.                                         |               |
                                                          |               |
Sem fringilla, id venenatis sem semper. Aenean malesuada  |               |
mi ac est convallis adipiscing. Sed vitae turpis congue   +---------------+
nulla ornare malesuada eget ac mi. Phasellus congue porttitor ultrices. Duis posuere
lorem at ipsum lacinia auctor. Aliquam pulvinar sollicitudin lectus sed vestibulum.
```

I have tried/can't do:

1. Moving the aside above the first paragraph is not an option because when the post is displayed in an RSS reader the aside is ignored and appears like a regular paragraph. If it is first then it appears before the first paragraph and doesn't make any sense.
2. I can't nest the aside into the middle of the paragraph because:

   - The aside is a block level element and it isn't valid to nest in the `<p>` element
   - Kramdown won't let me place the aside in the paragraph. (Because it knows it is a block level element?) When I try, the html is escaped so that "<aside>..." appears to the reader.
   - When read in an RSS reader the aside content would appear in the middle of my first paragraph, making no sense.
3. Position relative doesn't help because the text wraps around the aside's original location in the document.
4. My reading/searching suggested that using a negative `margin-top` would work, but it doesn't.  The paragraph text doesn't wrap around it. I assume this is because the aside is after the paragraph in the DOM.

**You can see my attempt to use negative margin and play with this on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnB37/3/).**

I was surprised the margin top didn't work because it seemed that negative margin left worked in a similar example on an old version of Pownce.com which you can see at http://web.archive.org/web/20071224051229/http://www.pownce.com/ Part way down the page the padlock image has a negative margin left to slide it out of the body of the text and the text wraps correctly.

Comment: You could float the paragraphs as well as the aside, although you lose true wrapping: http://jsfiddle.net/H8GuV/1/

Comment: If you can't move the `<aside>`, it won't really work with a negative margin. This only visually moves the element, as the `position` is still set to `:static` by default, hence why the `<p>` text flows right over it instead of wrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that works , but only if the aside size is known/fixed.

I have solved that making it scroll.

CSS

```
aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20em;
    height: 139px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: scroll;
}


h1:before {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 150px;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;    
}

.firstp:before {
    content: "";
    width: 22em;
    height: 160px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background-color: yellow;    
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnB37/4/)

I have set a class in the first p, *firstp*

Then, I need an floated right element before the p content, so that it flows ok. I use for this a pseudo element before on this class. This will be empty, and will be used only to reserve space for the aside element. The problem here is that I have to know the size of the aside, that I don't know. I have given this element yellow background, so that you can see easily what is happening.

To be able to position this where i want, I set another pseudo element on the h3. Setting this element height, and clearing the previous one, I can set the top position of it.

Finally, I set the aside with position absolute, in the space that is reserved.

Comment: I almost took an approach based on this answer where I used a wrapper div to provide a `position: relative` container for the absolutely positioned aside and a placeholder div with a copy of the aside content to match the aside's height (rather than making it fixed height).  This does seem to be the CSS answer.  I actually ended up using JavaScript which you can see in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22132908/268898).

Comment: By the way, a very well written question !

Answer (score 2):

I think the future way how to tackle this problem will be with [CSS Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/).

> CSS Exclusions extend the notion of content wrapping previously
>   limited to floats. ... Elements layout their inline content in their content area and wrap around the exclusion areas in their associated wrapping context (--excerpts from [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-exclusions/))

This [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh673558.aspx) also explains exclusions

> ...web authors can now wrap text so that it completely surrounds
>   elements, thereby avoiding the traditional limitations of floats.
>   Instead of limiting elements to floating either to the left or right
>   relative to their position in the document flow, CSS Exclusions can be
>   positioned at a specified distance from the top, bottom, left, or
>   right sides of a containing block, while remaining part of the
>   document flow.

Ironically, to date this only works in IE10 (look for wrap-flow:both [here](http://adobe.github.io/web-platform/utilities/css-exclusions-support-matrix/))

### Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/BnB37/9/) in IE10+

```
aside
{
    -ms-wrap-flow: both;
    -ms-wrap-margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:120px;
}
```

Because cross browser support is still lacking I have wrapped the above code in a media query which only gets executed in IE10+ so that the absolute positioning doesn't mess up the `float:right` property which is used in other browsers. (See [this impressive webs article](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/))

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* IE10+ specific styles go here */  
    aside
    {
        -ms-wrap-flow: both;
        -ms-wrap-margin: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        right:0;
        top:120px;
    }
}
```

**Regarding browser support:**

Check out [this site](http://adobe.github.io/web-platform/utilities/css-exclusions-support-matrix/) which shows which properties are supported by the browsers (to date: only IE10+ supports `wrap-flow:both` )

PS: Latest updates concerning CSS exclusions (and other simlar modules like CSS regions and CSS Shapes) can be found at the Adobe [Web Platform Team Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/)

Comment: I agree this looks like the future way to do it (hence the upvote), but since it doesn't work without the IE specific `-ms-wrap-flow` and `-ms-wrap-margin` I don't think it can be the answer today.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shape-outside: content-box;`. See [HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/) for the inspiration.

```css
aside {
  float: right;
  width: 20em;
  shape-outside: content-box;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

aside .content {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Blog Title</h1>
  <aside>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Aside Heading</h3>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <p>My first paragraph lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>My second paragraph lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for the problem as described because I was unable to put the aside before the first paragraph in the Html.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my fiddle for a reference- I just updated to show multiple paragraphs floating left and the aside floating right. You should just float your first paragraph then float the aside right. You can obviously play with the margin and size that I gave the elements. There shouldn't be any need for relative positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredczerew/b7jN3/

```
<body>
<h1>Blog Title</h1>
<section id="left">  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ac consequat erat, eu
Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus     
et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque pellentesque  
pretium felis, et adipiscing ante dapibus eget. Aenean    
nec lacinia eros.     
</section> 

<aside>
    <p> My aside content</p>
</aside>    
</body>


/** CSS **/
body {
width:100%
}
#left {
float:left;
width:70%;
 }
aside {
width:23%;
background:#ccc;
height:200px;
float:right;
text-align:center;
margin-top:30px
}
```

Comment: But you haven't actually wrapped the paragraph around the aside.  You've just hard coded the width so that for example if the paragraph is longer than the aside it will continue to be narrow instead of expanding to fill the body width.

Comment: I don't see how changing from right to left helps.  You still have a fixed width on the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

## If you are willing to use JavaScript

You can move the aside in the DOM so that it is before the first paragraph.  This allows the aside to be presented reasonably (as a centered box below the paragraph) when in an RSS reader or when JavaScript is disabled, but then easily allows the aside to float into the correct position, without so many CSS tricks, in the browser when the JavaScript runs.

To do this, I wrapped the paragraph and aside in a div. The wrapper div makes it easy to have it work in many different blog posts.  The HTML becomes:

```
<article>
  <h1>Blog Title</h1>
  <div class="with-aside">
    <p>My first paragraph...</p>
    <aside>
      <h3>Aside Heading</h3>
      <p>Aside content...</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <p>My second paragraph...</p>
</article>
```

The JavaScript then moves the aside before the paragraph inside the div.  I also add some classes so that different styles can be applied to the moved aside. Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) this can be done on document ready with:

```
$(function () {
    $('.with-aside').each(function (i, e) {
        var withAside = $(e);
        var aside = withAside.find('aside');
        aside.detach();
        aside.prependTo(withAside);
        aside.addClass('floating');
        withAside.addClass('floating');
    });
});
```

My CSS is then in three parts.  The first part styles the aside in a grey box (which applies whether it has been moved or not):

```
aside {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

The second applies when the JavaScript hasn't run and gives it left and right margin so it is set off nicely:

```
aside {
    margin: 0 5ex;
}
```

The last part applies when the JavaScript has run.  It floats the aside, pushes it down, and overrides the margins:

```
aside.floating {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 20em;
    margin: 0 0 0 1ex;
}
div.with-aside:before {
    content:"";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 3.75em; /* 3 lines (line-height is 1.25) */
}
```

### You can see all this in [jsfiddle.net/CH4Mr](http://jsfiddle.net/CH4Mr/)

Comment out the JavaScript and click run to see how it looks when the aside isn't moved. To see why the aside is pushed down, set `width: 3px; background-color: green;` on the `div.with-aside:before` and you will see the floating before pushing down the aside.

Thanks to @vals answer for the idea of using a `:before` floated to push the the float down.